# linking MySQL tables via foreign keys

Tags: mysql, database

I have created multiple tables in MySQL, yet data in some fields in one or more table should exist in other tables. I know that this can be created by adding foreign key to the table.

I would like to know how this can be done.

Please note that on deletion of any record all linked should NOT be deleted ... the value can be changed to null. I'll manage it in other way.

PS: I just need the code to do this.

Comment: why the down vote and close requests?!!

Comment: @Luchian: YES! and couldn't get to a good tutorial that can help. All I need is the way to alter the table to add a foreign key from another table.

Comment: I'm guessing because you obviously didn't try anything for yourself.

Comment: Odd...Am I correct that you want to set up relationships between tables to prevent duplication; yet you want to allow orphans to exist.  This isn't a relational design in any form I know.  Please rephrase: "data in some fields in one or more table should exist in other tables.  I know that this can be created by adding foreign key to the table." as this doesn't make logical sense to me

Comment: @Luchian: check Johan answer. This is what I was actually looking for!

Comment: @xQbert: check Johan answer. This is what I was actually looking for!

Comment: great! then be so kind as to accept their answer :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE other (
  id unsigned integer auto_increment primary key
  ,field1 varchar(100) not null) ENGINE = InnoDB;

CREATE TABLE example (
  id unsigned integer auto_increment primary key
  ,field1 varchar(100) not null
  ,other_id unsigned integer
  ,FOREIGN KEY FK_example_other_table (foreign_id) REFERENCES other(id) 
   ON DELETE RESTRICT
   ON UPDATE CASCADE ) ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

See: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html

Comment: can the `on update cascade` be ignored?

Comment: @sikas, the `ON DELETE` and `ON UPDATE` clauses are vital, because they determine how the foreign contraint will work.  You should always set these by hand and never rely on a default because the default will likely not do what you want (and it will cause you to spend unneeded time in debugging trying to figure out why you get foreign key check errors).

Comment: I'll be only linking by ID, so if the ID data changes, the ID will remain the same unless record is removed. So the on update will not be needed. And the on delete will have to set the value to null until I link with another record.

Comment: `on delete restrict`, does this keep the record and put the value with null?

Comment: @sikas, please follow the link and read. `RESTRICT` forbids the delete.